# Random walk exercise for r.v. $X_n = |RW_n|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Below is part of the solution for an exercise in a book. $X_n = |S_n|$ where $S_n$ is a common walk, $B$ is some event. The question is not about chains though. I can't understand what formula was used to write this equality. I suppose it should be something like $P(A|C\cup D)$ but can't deduce it the way they use.

[image: solution]

Comment: If $P(C|B_1)\neq 0$, then $P(A|B_1) = P(A|C)P(C|B_1)$. Also use additivity of probability.

Comment: Use the fact that, if $(B_k)$ is a partition of $B$ then $$P(A\mid B)=\sum_kP(A\mid B_k)P(B_k\mid B).$$

Comment: @zhoraster Sure about your comment?

Comment: @zhoraster Still wrong.

Comment: @Did, yes, my head is a strainer last days. $P(A\cap C|B_1) = P(A|C\cap B_1)P(C|B_1)$. Now should be right.

Comment: @zhoraster But now the problem is how to apply this to the question.

Comment: @Did, take $C_{\pm} = \{S_i = \pm 1\}$ and add. Which essentially coincides with your comment, of course.

Comment: @zhoraster Right, in other words one can use your remark for *several* sets $C$. This makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! $B_k \cap B = B_k$ that is what I was missing :)